# would like to how to list the *.gz file names alone by searching each of those *.gz files for a given string

Tags: unix, find, names

I need help in finding the names of those `*.gz` files which should contain a string [ I am searching for a string within a set of `*.gz` files ].

I want the result of the command to be only the file names .

When I execute below command :

`find . -name \*2020Jul25*.gz -print0 | zargs -0 zgrep -v "string I am looking for"`

above returns all the `*.gz` names followed by lines of text withing each `*.gz` which contains my search criteria.

Can someone help me in only getting the `*.gz` file name alone Please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share input and expected output by editing post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU grep, the `-l` option means:

> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match.

And if all the files are in the same directory, you don't need `find`:

```
zgrep -Fl "string I am looking for" *2020Jul25*.gz
```

(Use `-F` when searching for a string instead of a regular expression pattern.)